# How to serialize HashMap<Object,Object> with GSON?

Tags: java, hashmap, gson

I am trying to serialize HashMap which has custom objects (both of the same type) both as a key and a value. However gson is outputing something like this:

```
{ key.toString():{value}}
```

Basicaly instead of serializing the object used as key in the map it just uses its toString value. The value object gets serialized fine. Resulting Json obviously cannot be deserialized. How do I convince GSON to fully serialize the key object?

EDIT:
The objects that are stored in HashMap contains information about players (I am building custom matchmaker for our board game group). They look like this:

```
public class Player implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
private String playerName,faction,teamName;
private HashMap<String,Integer> resources;
```

The hashmap is supposed to contain informations about upcoming matches, basicaly key playing against value like this:

```
HashMap<Player,Player> matchMap=new HashMap<>();
matchMap.put(player1,opponentForPlayer1);
```

Comment: How do you expect the output json to look? Keys in json are strings.

Comment: I was hoping for something like this:
`{ {key} : {value} }`
Or, more generaly, something that can be deserialized back to HashMap<Object,Object>.

Comment: @BrackenAlistair BeUndead is suggesting you a right question to ask. `{{}:{}}` is not a JSON, you have to learn JSON syntax first. Keys can only be strings. So either use `Map<String, ...>` (don't know why you need your keys), or use https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization-- that will produce a pair-elements array JSON like `[[k1,v1],[k2,v2]]`. Anyway you have to review your approach and use string keys.

Comment: @fluffy enableComplexMapKeySerialization() was exactly what I was looking for, do you want to submit it as answer so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on fluffys comment the simplest solution is using enableComplexMapKeySerialization() while creating gson object like this:

```
Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
```

If that is not available or working for whatever reason [pcsutars answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68017628/3407157) also work.

Comment: I was having an issue of the keys of my Map<Object, Object> not being correctly serialized, by default Gson was using KeyObject.toString() for serialization despite registering a custom adapter for that Object - enabling this option did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` keys can only be `Strings`. Try below solution which uses custom `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`.

Custom `JsonSerializer` which will convert key (`Player` object) to JSON `String` while serialization:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class CustomMapSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Map<Player, Player>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Map<Player, Player> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        for (Entry<Player, Player> entry : src.entrySet()) {
            json.add(gson.toJson(entry.getKey()), gson.toJsonTree(entry.getValue()));
        }

        return json;
    }

}
```

Custom `JsonDeserializer` to convert key (JSON `String`) back to `Player` object during deserialization :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class CustomMapDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Map<Player, Player>> {

    @Override
    public Map<Player, Player> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        Map<Player, Player> players = new HashMap<Player, Player>();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();

        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
            players.put(gson.fromJson(entry.getKey(), Player.class), gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), Player.class));
        }

        return players;
    }
}
```

Refer below example for `serialization` and `deserialization`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Solutiony {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("value", 100);

        Player p = new Player();
        p.setFaction("0.9");
        p.setPlayerName("x");
        p.setTeamName("A");
        p.setResources(data);

        Player p2 = new Player();
        p2.setFaction("1.0");
        p2.setPlayerName("y");
        p2.setTeamName("B");
        p2.setResources(data);

        Map<Player, Player> map = new HashMap<Player, Player>();
        map.put(p, p2);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(map.getClass(), new CustomMapSerializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(map.getClass(), new CustomMapDeserializer())
                .setPrettyPrinting().create();

        //Serialization
        String val = gson.toJson(map);

        //De-serialization
        Map<Player, Player> map2 = gson.fromJson(val, map.getClass());
    }
}
```

Serialized `JSON` will look like:

```
{
  "{\"playerName\":\"x\",\"faction\":\"0.9\",\"teamName\":\"A\",\"resources\":{\"value\":100}}": {
    "playerName": "y",
    "faction": "1.0",
    "teamName": "B",
    "resources": {
      "value": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is definitely _a_ solution, I would have questions to ask if someone was trying to merge that into a code based I worked on 

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to come up with an exact answer without a specific example.

You can change how the key is named using the `SerializedName` annotation:

```java
private class SomeObject {
  @SerializedName("custom_naming") private final String someField;
  private final String someOtherField;

  public SomeObject(String a, String b) {
    this.someField = a;
    this.someOtherField = b;
  }
}

SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject("first", "second");
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
String jsonRepresentation = gson.toJson(someObject);
System.out.println(jsonRepresentation);
```

The output is:

```json
{"custom_naming": "first", "SomeOtherField": "second"}
```

(example shamelessly stolen from the doc :)

To customize the serialization, check out the documentation : https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#custom-serialization-and-deserialization

```java
// Step 1: writing a custom serializer


/** Here is an example of how to write a custom serializer for JodaTime DateTime class. */
private class DateTimeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<DateTime> {
  public JsonElement serialize(DateTime src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
  }
}
```

```java
// Step 2: registering it
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyType.class, new DateTimeSerializer());
```

> registerTypeAdapter call checks if the type adapter implements more than one of these interfaces and register it for all of them.